# Issue with website render tearing in Webkit on iOS browsers

Tags: javascript, ios, css, reactjs, gatsby

There seems to be some rendering issue with my website on iOS webview browsers (safari, chrome, and firefox).  The issue only shows up on iOS devices, cannot replicate on pc, mac, or android devices.

The site initially renders perfectly. The screen tearing only shows up after several reloads of the page.  Another way to replicate it is to lock the device, wait a few seconds, then open the device and the tearing has come back.

I have tried removing elements of the page, animations, and react components with no luck.  Looking into the web developer tools in safari, no errors are coming up.

The website is being built using Gatsbyjs a static site generator, reactstrap for bootstrap and fontawesome for fonts.  There are some animated svg elements on the page, but removing them does nothing to help the problem.

I initially thought it was some kind of memory leak in react, so I removed all my react logic and the issue continued.

Any ideas to aid in the debugging of the issue would be greatly appreciated.

[Screenshot of screen tearing on webpage render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MANC.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Found the issue after hours of pulling out my hair.

The issue seems to be with utilizing filter:drop-shadow in the css.

```
.shadowed-alpha {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22));
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22));
}
```

After removing the drop-shadow from my div, the issue went away.  Can't seem to find any documentation on the issue.  Box-shadows work fine, drop-shadows do not. I need the alpha based drop-shadow filter for a transparent png I am using, but for now I have left it out on iOS until I can find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing this myself on a recent project. At first I thought it was a lack of `clip-path` support, as we're using that as well on our project, but nope, it is `filter: drop-shadow`.

It's really hard to reproduce but with enough scaling, zooming, and panning, it occasionally presents itself.

I made a codepen demonstrating the issue: https://codepen.io/seanmaisch/full/BgZxbx